# Determine the domain, co-domain and range

Tags: functions

I am trying to determine the domain, co-domain and range of the following function

**A function assigns to each bit string, the number of zeroes in that bit string.**

I imagine that this will be that "function" is Domain, "String" is Co-domain and "number of zeroes" is range?

will this then be:
f = function
x = sting
y = zeroes

and then f(x)=y ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **domain** of a function is the set of things that the function operates on.  The **range** of a function is the set of values that the function actually produces.  The **co-domain** is every value that the function can produce, whether or not it does produce them.  The **co-domain** and **range** may coincide, or may not.

In your case: the set of all bit strings is the collection of all strings consisting of $1$s and $0$s of any length.  The set $\{0,1\}$ gives us a choice of either $1$ or $0$, and $\{0,1\}^n$ gives us a string of $n$ concatenated $0$s and $1$s.  So since we need all possible lengths, we have to take a union, and we get $$X=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \{0,1\}^n$$
This is the **domain** of the function.  Note that $n=0$ corresponds to the empty string with no $0$s or $1$s.

Your function calculates the number of $0$s in the string.  Since there must be at least $0$ zeroes, and can be infinitely many $0$s, we see that the **co-domain** must be ${\mathbb N}_0$ (people who wish to argue over whether the natural numbers should include zero or not may find the appropriate thread themselves).

Finally we observe that there are no elements of the **co-domain** that the function cannot produce given a string of the right length (for example, the string $"000\ldots0$ of length $n$ is valid for all $n$), so the **range** is the same as the **co-domain**.

So your function is $$f:X \rightarrow {\mathbb N}_0$$ and is surjective.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, it was really helpful. 
The next one I am trying to solve is **A function assigns to each integer, the square of that integer multiplied on 4.** - what is have come up with is: **f:  X→√ℤ*4** but I feel like I might have some symbols in the wrong place for this one?

Comment: @CUPA You need to post it as a new question :)  The site dislikes posting questions in comments, and it's easier for other people seeking help to find questions if they're not in comments