# Determine the domain, co-domain and range - again

Tags: functions

I am trying to determine the domain, co-domain and range of the following function

**A function assigns to each integer, the square of that integer multiplied on 4.**

What I think it is, is: f: X→√ℤ*4

But I suspect that I have some of the symbols in the wrong place?

I previously posted a similar question:

**A function assigns to each bit string, the number of zeroes in that bit string.**

[And got a really good answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112804/determine-the-domain-co-domain-and-range/3112877?noredirect=1#comment6416349_3112877)

Comment: What does $\sqrt Z$ mean above? Also, what is $X$?

Comment: Based on that previous answer, what do you think the domain of this function might be ("a function assigns to each *integer* ..." - that's a big clue) ? What do you think the range might be ? Don't worry about symbols for now, just say what you think the answers might be in words. Co-domain requires a bit more thought because in this case not everything in the range is in the co-domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like last time, take things one step at a time.  For the **domain** we're told that $f$ acts on the integers, so the domain is going to be all of $\mathbb{Z}$.  We're told that $f$ acts by squaring its argument and multiplying by $4$, so we know that $f(x)=4x^2$.  Since any integer multiplied by an integer yields another integer, we can see that the **co-domain** must be some subset of the integers again.  But it's not *all* of the integers, because squaring an integer always gives us a positive integer.  We can write that as ${\mathbb Z}^+$ or ${\mathbb N}$ -- in this case, I'll choose the first to emphasize that this is a subset of the integers.  So $$f:{\mathbb Z} \rightarrow {\mathbb Z}^+$$
Finally, the **range** is only a subset of the positive integers -- for example, there is no $x$ such that $f(x) = 3$.  In fact, only positive integer multiples of $4$ can be in the range of $f$ because $f(x)=4x^2$.  So the range is a set: $$ \mbox{Ran}(f) = \{ x\in {\mathbb Z}^+ : 4|x \mbox{ and } x \mbox{ is square} \} $$

Answer (score 4):

I think you are principally confused with notation. The notation $f:X\rightarrow Y$ just specifies that $f$ is a function from its domain $X$ to its codomain $Y$ -  it doesn't specify how the function is defined.

E.g. Let $g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$. We now need to specify how $g$ maps an integer to an integer. An example would be $g: x\mapsto 2x$ which is equivalent to the notation $g(x) = 2x$ where we double the input.

In your case you are told that your function $f$ maps from the integers and are given the rule, namely $f(x) = 4x^2.$